# Как стрелочная функция получает данный контекст?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const PlayerAPI = {
  players: [
    { number: 1, name: "Ben Blocker", position: "G" },
    { number: 2, name: "Dave Defender", position: "D" },
    { number: 3, name: "Sam Sweeper", position: "D" },
    { number: 4, name: "Matt Midfielder", position: "M" },
    { number: 5, name: "William Winger", position: "M" },
    { number: 6, name: "Fillipe Forward", position: "F" }
  ],
  all: function() { return this.players},
  get: function(id) {
    const isPlayer = p => p.number === id
    return this.players.find(isPlayer)
  }
}
```

При использовании метода `get` его аргумент сравнивается поочерёдно с каждым обьектом в массиве players. `PlayerAPI.get(2);`

Не ясно почему стрелочная функция работает именно с этим массивом, это ведь не указано нигде.

Если рядом дописать свойство в котором будет другой массив, то данный метод get все равно почему-то "выбирает" для обработки массив `players`. Почему?

Comment: _это ведь не указано нигде._ - указано, ты же сам передаешь ее в метод find: `this.players.find(isPlayer)`

Comment: да ,понял. спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
get: function(id) {
  const isPlayer = p => p.number === id
  return this.players.find(isPlayer)
}
```

Ключевое слово `function` создает обычную функцию, а не стрелочную.

Ключевое слово `this`, внутри функции, указывает на объект, в котором она вызвана. Здесь `PlayerAPI.get(2)` вы явно вызываете функцию `get` в контексте `PlayerAPI`. Это говорит о том что `this` внутри `get` указывает на объект `PlayerAPI`. В данном случае `this.players.find(isPlayer)` равно `PlayerAPI.players.find(isPlayer)`

Надеюсь, что правильно понял вопрос.

Comment: да, спасибо.суть была в том чтобы разобраться как в строке `const isPlayer = p => p.number === id` в `p` вообще что-то попадает. Нужно было просто взглянуть на следующую строку.